# Unrecognized COMMAND/service 'chipper,' how to find host package?

Tags: apt, apache2, snap, services, software-uninstall

I'm trying to run a local apache server on a dedicated ubuntu `22.04.1 LTS` server machine. However, I can't get apache2 to start. Every time I try `sudo systemctl restart apache2` I'm told that it failed to start because another service is listening on port 80.

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
apachectl
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

After running `sudo lsof -i -P -n` I can see a `COMMAND` called `chipper` is running as root and hogging port 80.
`sudo kill [that pid]` worked, but it started itself back up before i could restart apache. This isn't a package I recognize, and neither `sudo apt remove chipper` or `sudo snap remove chipper` were helpful. How can I find out what package this service is a part of and determine what action I want to take to free this port?

UPDATE:
Chipper is a part of DDL's Escape Pod for Vector. Though my source problem is now resolved, I'd still like to know how to find a `COMMAND`'s source package, if possible.

UPDATE 2:
The idea behind this question is finding the source of a command given only a command name and PID. I was able to get apache to restart fast enough to outpace the port 80 hog, and that allowed me to see the source in the logs when it failed to run (because now apache has port 80). Originally, all i had was a field called `COMMAND` and `PID,` so I think it would be useful to know how to find the source package for the output of the `sudo lsof -i -P -n` command. This is not about finding the source package of an existing file, because if I had the file from the start I would have seen the directory it was contained in (in this case, `~/wire-pod/` would have answered my question before i even asked it).

Comment: There's no such command in [the official repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=jammy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=chipper), so you'd have to use `dpkg -S` to see if it was provided by some package.

Comment: That requires a file name, which I don't have. So would I be correct in assuming that there is no way to work backwards from just a PID to find the package or file responsible for the PID?

Comment: Usually the process name is the filename of the executable, so if you see a process named `chipper`, the file is also likely to be named `chipper`. You can check what file is actually running using `ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe`

Comment: Awesome, thank you! That means the answer to "How to find the source of a known but unrecognized PID" is to run `ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe` followed by `dpkg -S` on the identified file. Thanks again!